# how to get value from a dictionary in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I have arrays, which structure is:

```
var data = [["name" : "Piter", "pubDate" = "01"], ["name" : "Tomas", "pubDate" : "02"], ["name" : "Troy", "pubDate" : "03"]]

var newData = [[String:String]]?
```

and now I would like to check if there is for example "pubDate" = 01, if yes, I would like to add this row (all data from this row) to new table. I do something like this:

```
for _ in data{

  if data[indexPath.item]["pubDate"] == "01"{

    newData!.append(data[indexPath.item])

    }

}
```

but my code doesn't work. Do you have any idea, how can I find value which I need and add whole row to new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are is a typo in your code:

```
["name" : "Piter", "pubDate" = "01"]
```

It should be:

```
["name" : "Piter", "pubDate" : "01"]
```

I have a working solution here:

```
        let data = [["name" : "Piter", "pubDate" : "01"], ["name" : "Tomas", "pubDate" : "02"], ["name" : "Troy", "pubDate" : "03"]]

        var newData = [[String:String]]()

        for dictionary in data {
            if dictionary["pubDate"] == "01" {
                newData.append(dictionary)
            }
        }

        print(newData);
```

Comment: great it works! funy is, I done it before, but I had optional newData array and it was a problem. THX for hint!

Comment: it works, but i see this loop doesn't stop. I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that using the `filter` method:

```
let newData = data.filter { $0["pubDate"] == "01" }
```

No need to loop, a simple one-liner.

Comment: but when I do newData.append(dataFiltered) recive information "cannot convert value of type [[String:String]]? to expected argument type [String:String]"

Comment: @Berike i changed the code a tiny bit, what you get ***is*** already `newData`!

Answer (score 0):

You can Enumerate an Array of Dictionary like this way

```
let dataArray:Array<Dictionary<String,String>>  = [["name" : "Piter", "pubDate" : "01"], ["name" : "Tomas", "pubDate" : "02"], ["name" : "Troy", "pubDate" : "03"]]

    var newData = [String:String]()

    for dict in dataArray{

        for (key,value) in dict{

            if value == "01"{

                newData[key] = value
                print(newData)
            }

        }

    }
```

Hope will will solve your problem